# What is the darkling personality?

Tags: the-darkness-2

When you start a new game, you can select the darkling personality. What is it?

You can choose between `hooligan`:

[image]

and `abdul`:

[image]

What is the difference? How does it affect gameplay?

Comment: I don't have this, so I can't confirm, but wasn't a preorder bonus an alternate skin for the darkling?  I'm assuming this is all that is.

Comment: I think there was something like this in the first game that affected what they sounded like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just the 2 different darkling outfits you can choose your darkling to wear. Hooligan is the standard one and Abdul is the 'Crazy Abdul' outfit that you get with the limited edition version of the game. As far as I'm aware, it does not affect the game in any other way apart from the appearance of the darkling.

Answer (score 1):

I started a game with the `hooligan` personality, and sometimes my darkling puts on an England soccer shirt and urinates while dancing.

I will update the answer when I get a chance to play it with `abdul`, but it appears that it only affects jokes and dialog, nothing gameplay-wise.